# Convert dataframe to JSON with 2 level nested array

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I am a bit new to Python programming. I have a small requirement where in I need to list down all customers and their amounts for a given fortnight in a JSON format.

Currently, I have a dataframe this way:

```
  FortNight      Amount     Customer    Parameter
  Apr-2FN-2018   339632.00    10992     CustomerSales
  Apr-2FN-2018   27282.00     10994     CustomerSales 
  Apr-2FN-2018   26353.00     10995     CustomerSales 
  Apr-2FN-2018   24797.00     11000     CustomerSales
  Apr-2FN-2018   21093.00     10990     CustomerSales
```

Expected JSON:

```
"CustomerSales" : [                                                                
    {"FortNight" : "Apr-2FN-2018",                                                                                      
         "Details" :[
             {"Customer":  "10992","Amount" : 339632.00},                                                                                                                                
             {"Customer":  "10994","Amount" : 27282.00},
             {"Customer":  "10995","Amount" : 26353.00},  
             {"Customer":  "11000","Amount" : 24797.00},
             {"Customer":  "10990","Amount" : 21093.00}
           ]
    }
]
```

I tried:

```
dict(df.set_index('Parameter').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda  x : ast.literal_eval(x.to_json(orient = 'records', date_format = "iso"))))
```

It retrieves this:

```
 [{'CustomerSales': 
[{'Customer': '10992', 'Amount': 339632.00, 'FortNight': 'Apr-2FN-2018'}, {'Customer': '10994', 'Amount': 27282.00, 'FortNight': 'Apr-2FN-2018'},{'Customer': '10995', 'Amount': 26353.00, 'FortNight': 'Apr-2FN-2018'},
{'Customer': '11000', 'Amount': 24797.00, 'FortNight': 'Apr-2FN-2018'},
{'Customer': '10990', 'Amount': 21093.00, 'FortNight': 'Apr-2FN-2018'}]}]
```

I tried other ways too but in vain. Any help is welcome. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Never** use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse JSON. It's slower, and will produce errors the moment you have boolean or null values. Besides, converting to JSON then parsing back to a dictionary means you really just wanted to produce a dictionary to begin with by a more direct path.

Comment: You also don't need to set the index to `Parameter` when grouping by that column. Just use `df.groupby('Parameter')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by grouping on both the Parameter *and* FortNight columns, and using `.to_dict()` on the resulting grouped rows to produce the inner-most dictionaries:

```
details = df.groupby(['Parameter', 'FortNight']).apply(
    lambda r: r[['Customer', 'Amount']].to_dict(orient='records'))
```

This gives you a series with a multi-index over `Parameter` and `FortNight`, and the values are all the lists in the correct format, each entry a dictionary with `Customer` and `Amount` columns. If you need to convert the value types, do so on the `r[['Customer', 'Amount']]` dataframe result before calling `to_dict()` on it.

You can then [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) the series into a dataframe, giving you a nested Parameter -> FortNight -> details structure; the Parameter values become columns, each list of Customer / Amount dictionaries indexed by FortNight:

```
nested = details.unstack('Parameter')
```

If you turn this into a dictionary, you'd get a dictionary that's mostly correct already:

```
>>> pprint(grouped.unstack('Parameter').to_dict())
{'CustomerSales': {'Apr-2FN-2018': [{'Amount': 339632.0, 'Customer': '10992'},
                                    {'Amount': 27282.0, 'Customer': '10994'},
                                    {'Amount': 26353.0, 'Customer': '10995'},
                                    {'Amount': 24797.0, 'Customer': '11000'},
                                    {'Amount': 21093.0, 'Customer': '10990'}]}}
```

but for your format, you'd convert the values in each column to a list of `{'FortNight': indexvalue, 'Details': value}` mappings, *then* converting the whole structure to a dictionary:

```
output = nested.apply(lambda s: [
    {s.index.name: idx, 'Details': value}
    for idx, value in s.items()
]).to_dict('records')
```

This gives you your final output:

```
>>> pprint(output)
[{'CustomerSales': {'Details': [{'Amount': 339632.0, 'Customer': '10992'},
                                {'Amount': 27282.0, 'Customer': '10994'},
                                {'Amount': 26353.0, 'Customer': '10995'},
                                {'Amount': 24797.0, 'Customer': '11000'},
                                {'Amount': 21093.0, 'Customer': '10990'}],
                    'FortNight': 'Apr-2FN-2018'}}]
```

If you need a JSON document, use `.to_json(orient='records')` rather than `.to_dict('records')`.

Put together as one expression:

```
df.groupby(['Parameter', 'FortNight']).apply(
        lambda r: r[['Customer', 'Amount']].to_dict(orient='records')
    ).unstack('Parameter').apply(lambda s: [
        {s.index.name: idx, 'Details': value}
        for idx, value in s.items()]
    ).to_json(orient='records')
```