# Pandas multiple group by to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am having some trouble getting the following dataframe to a JSON structure. I've tried a few things but can't quite get to the last bit.
So I have a data frame with the following

```
  serialNumber |    date    | part  | value | name
 --------------|------------|-------|-------|---------------- 
  ABC0001      | 01/10/2019 | Part1 | ABC1  | ABC            
  ABC0001      | 01/10/2019 | Part1 | ABC2  | XYZ            
  ABC0001      | 02/10/2019 | Part2 | ABC3  | ASF            
  ABC0001      | 02/10/2019 | Part2 | ABC4  | TSR
```

And need it in the format of

```
  { "SerialNumber": "ABC001",
    "detail": [  { "part": "Part1",
                   "date":"01/10/2019",
                   "extras": [  { "value": "ABC1",
                                  "name": "ABC"
                                },
                                { "value": "ABC2",
                                  "name": "XYZ"
                                }]
                 },
                 { "part": "Part2",
                   "date":"02/10/2019",
                   "extras": [   { "value": "ABC3",
                                  "name": "ASF"
                                },
                                { "value": "ABC4",
                                  "name": "TSR"
                                }]
              ]
     }
```

So grouping serialnumber, then data and part, then value and name.
I've had a look at some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998624/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308824/convert-dataframe-to-json-with-2-level-nested-with-groupby), the last one helped a lot

```
df.groupby(['serialNumber', 'Part']).apply(
        lambda r: r[['Value', 'identifierName']].to_dict(orient='records')
    ).unstack('serialNumber').apply(lambda s: [
        {s.index.name: idx, 'detail=': value}
        for idx, value in s.items()]
    ).to_json(orient='records')
```

which gives me

```
[
   {
      "ABC0001":{
         "Part":"Part1",
         "detail=":[
            {
               "Value":"ABC1",
               "identifierName":"ABC"
            },
            {
               "Value":"ABC2",
               "identifierName":"XYZ"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "ABC0001":{
         "Part":"Part2",
         "detail=":[
            {
               "Value":"ABC3",
               "identifierName":"ASF"
            },
            {
               "Value":"ABC4",
               "identifierName":"TSR"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

but breaks down when I add Date, and doesn't show the label of serial number
Suggestions?? tips?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default function in pandas to solve this.

This nesting code iterates through each level of the `MultIndex`, adding layers to the dictionary until the deepest layer is assigned to the `Series` value.

This will work for any number of nesting folds:

`grouped = df.set_index(['serialNumber', 'Part'])`

```
import json

levels = grouped.ndim
dicts = [{} for i in range(levels)]
last_index = None

for index,value in enumerate(grouped.itertuples(), 1):

    if not last_index:
        last_index = index

    for (ii,(i,j)) in enumerate(zip(index, last_index)):
        if not i == j:
            ii = levels - ii -1
            dicts[:ii] =  [{} for _ in dicts[:ii]]
            break

    for i, key in enumerate(reversed(index)):
        dicts[i][key] = value
        value = dicts[i]

    last_index = index


result = json.dumps(dicts[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've just ran a test and got 'Cannot access callable attribute 'itertuples' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method' I'm just reading the csv file into a dataframe, then running the above code? Suggestions?

Comment: Yes I understood the problem and fixed it

Comment: Sorry, one more, I;ve tried to debug it, now getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @Jonee Which line?

Comment: for index,value in grouped.itertuples()

Comment: @Jonee Sorry I missed an `enumerate`

Comment: sorry I'm getting a error -  zip argument #1 must support iteration on the line
---> 12     for (ii,(i,j)) in enumerate(zip(index, last_index)):