# Convert Dataframe to Json with nested arrays

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe `df` as shown below

```
   ID               Aisle            Residence        HomePhone        CellPhone
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  1245,3214        A1, A2, A3, A4   Home             NaN              888888888
1  5674             B2,B3            Cell             777777777        999999999
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
 "0":{
    {
      "column": "ID",
      "values": [
        "1245",
        "3214"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "Aisle",
      "values": [
        "A1",
        "A2",
        "A3",
        "A4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "Residence",
      "values": [
        "Home"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "HomePhone",
      "values": []
    },
    {
      "column": "CellPhone",
      "values": [
        "888888888"
      ]
    }
   },
"1":{
    {
      "column": "ID",
      "values": [
        "5674"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "Aisle",
      "values": [
        "B2",
        "B3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "Residence",
      "values": [
        "Cell"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "HomePhone",
      "values": [
        "777777777"
      ]
    },
    {
      "column": "CellPhone",
      "values": [
        "999999999"
      ]
    }
   },
```

I have 2 rows which are `0` and `1`, and the json has the information under them for each row.
So basically, I want to add attributes and assign them to values that are column names, such as `"column":"Aisle"`,`"values":["A1","B1,...]"`

Also, I have a restriction that the column names always change (ID, Aisle, Residence...etc) and the number of columns vary, so I cannot hard code columns when converting from DF to JSON.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304738/convert-dataframe-to-json-with-2-level-nested-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the closest thing to what you are looking for.Use [`DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
df2=df.copy()
df2[['ID','Aisle']]=df2[['ID','Aisle']].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ','').str.split(','))
print(df2)
```

---

```
             ID                Aisle Residence    HomePhone  CellPhone
0  [1245, 3214]  [A1,  A2,  A3,  A4]      Home          NaN  888888888
1        [5674]             [B2, B3]      Cell  777777777.0  999999999
```

---

```
df2.T.to_json()
```

Output:

```
'{"0":{"ID":["1245","3214"],"Aisle":["A1"," A2"," A3"," A4"],"Residence":"Home","HomePhone":null,"CellPhone":888888888},"1":{"ID":["5674"],"Aisle":["B2","B3"],"Residence":"Cell","HomePhone":777777777.0,"CellPhone":999999999}}'
```

---

You can also try this:

```
def split_func(x):
    try:
        return x.replace(' ','').str.split(',') 
    except:
        return x
df2=df2.apply(split_func)
```

**but keep in mind that all str type cells would be converted to list**

```
df2.T.to_json()
```

---

```
'{"0":{"ID":["1245","3214"],"Aisle":["A1","A2","A3","A4"],"Residence":["Home"],"HomePhone":null,"CellPhone":888888888},"1":{"ID":["5674"],"Aisle":["B2","B3"],"Residence":["Cell"],"HomePhone":777777777.0,"CellPhone":999999999}}'
```

Comment: thanks for your response. What if the column names change? Is there a way to do it without restricting my self with the column exact names?

Comment: I am glad to help:).I have added an additional code for this case

Comment: check my answer please