# Transform pandas dataframe to json

Tags: json, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Group | Input Name | Input Country | multiplier | TargetName | TargetCountry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | AFP | UK | 1.0 | FSS | France |
| v1 | AFP | UK | 1.0 | BAGE | Spain |
| v1 | IUM | USA | 1.0 | FSS | France |
| v1 | IUM | USA | 1.0 | BAGE | Spain |
| v1 | AFP | UK | 1.0 | CS | France |
| v1 | IUM | USA | 1.0 | CS | France |
| v1 | TION | Ireland | 1.0 | INES | Austria |

And would like to get into a json format:

```
{
 "Group": "v1"
 "Input":
         {
          "InputName": ["AFP", "IUM"],
          "InputCountry": ["UK", "USA"],
          "multiplier": 1
          },
"Target":
         {
          "France": ["FSS", "CS"],
          "Spain": "BAGE"
         },
},

{
 "Group": "v1"
 "Input":
         {
          "InputName": "TION",
          "InputCountry": "Ireland",
          "multiplier": None
          },
"Target":
         {
          "Austria": "INES,
         },
}
```

I'm struggling with how to apply groupby and how to add the additional indices "Input" and "Target". Thanks for your help!

I tried something similar based on this post but didn't manage to get the desired result.
[Convert dataframe to JSON with 2 level nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304738/convert-dataframe-to-json-with-2-level-nested-array)

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the grouping/split ?

Comment: .Thanks for your comment.
Basically, TargetNames are assigned to one or several InputName. TargetNames are then categorized by TargetCountry.
The json shows which TargetNames are assinged to InputName(s) and groups the TargetNames by TargetCountry.

For example,: The TargetNames FSS, CS and BAGE are assigned to the InputNames AFP and IUM. The TargetNames are then further grouped by their TargetCountries: France and Spain